# Unable to simulate Smart-car-use-case solution

Tags: edgeengine

I am working on mimik **Smart-car-use-case Solution**. I took both the device, **Car1** and **Car2** as **RaspberryPi** Board. Then how will i do the Postman Simulation, Since it is not supported with Pi,

And I have an image of obstacle in **Car-1(in **Pi Board1**)**, which can be viewed by **car-2** (**Pi Board2**), So the image path in ***"[C2] → mSuperdrive mimik add a media Obj locally (Car 1)"*** api call should be a filepath of an image in **Pi-board1**

In this case how can i give the **image path** in Postman.

Answer (score 0):

Since postman is not supported, I cannot advise on any further alternative  solutions. The solution requires postman so its best to use a PI image that supports Postman. Periodically check [here](https://developer.mimik.com/smart-car-use-case/) to see if there are updates to the package.

For information on how to send and image via Postman, please view answers below:

["Post Image data using POSTMAN"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660074/post-image-data-using-postman)